# iPhone keyboard pushes page up in phonegap

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an iOS app in phonegap / cordova 3.3.0 with jquery mobile 1.4.2

I have designed a page with multiple textboxes for input but when iPhones native keyboard opens it pushes page up in iphone 4, in an iphone 5 also i face same issue but page comes to original state after closing keyboard, but in iphone 4 page stucks at the top in pushed position. Check screen shots below.
[image] 

this is screen

this is when keyboard open
[image]

after closing keyboard is closed
[image]

please help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap Page scroll up after Keyboard appearance in iOS devices that makes the PhoneGap page corrupted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000660/phonegap-page-scroll-up-after-keyboard-appearance-in-ios-devices-that-makes-the)

Comment: @jeekonline, thanks buddy. This link helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now you can add a:

`document.body.scrollTop = 0;`

whenever the input field fires a blur event.

courtesy: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15245604/1559484)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's relevant anymore, but i will add it anyway cause it fix my issue,
i just added:

```
  window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', function(){
                            window.scrollTo(0,0);
                        });
```

and it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar situations but I need to keep the focused field at bottom. Notice that I cater the situations for different iphone models based on the window size.

```
  function fixKeyboardOffset(){
    var iOSOffset = 0;
    switch ($(window).height()){
      case 716 : iOSOffset = 340; break;
      case 647 : iOSOffset = 285; break; 
      case 548 : iOSOffset = 190; break;  
      case 460 : iOSOffset = 110; break;  
    }
    if (device.platform == 'iOS'){
        $('#comment-field').on('focus', function(e) {
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#content_comment_container").offset().top - iOSOffset
          }, 0);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

This is how I solved same issue in phonegap build.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried this but didnt helped.