# How to configure keyboard using Phonegap in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

is it possible to hide this line, and touch outside to dismiss keyboard using Phonegap?

[image]

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000660/phonegap-page-scroll-up-after-keyboard-appearance-in-ios-devices-that-makes-the) may be helpful to for this situation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because PhoneGap uses a webview to display the app/contents and, therefore, uses the default `UIWebView` keyboard.

This is one of many drawbacks of non-native coding.