# IOS 7 keyboard leaves white block when deactivated (phonegap)

Tags: html, ios, cordova

I am working on a phonegap application for IOS and I came across a problem.
Every time I open the keyboard and **tap above it** to close it it leaves a large white block on my screen.
[image]
As you can see in the gif above it is easily repairable by exiting the keyboard using the "done" button, but I like to have the same behavior when tapping on "zoek dossiers" for instance..

I think this is something that has to be solved in the xCode files instead of the html but here is my page anyway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/assyst_app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<header>
  <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left transitions" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
      <a id="su">Instellingen<span id="navIcon" class="icon-cog"></span></a>
      <a id="lo">Log uit<span id="navIcon" class="icon-logout"></span></a>
  </nav>
  <div class="navBar">
    <button class="navBut bgCol" id="showLeft" ><span class="icon-menu"></span></button>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<body onLoad="onLoadHolder()">
<div id="art">
<article id="relCont">          <!--            Phone               -->
    <form id="dossier-zoek">
        <input type="text" id="sea" name="search" class="regTXTBOX brdrCol" placeholder="Zoek">
        <button id="searchDos" class="bgCol">Zoek dossiers</button>
    </form>
    <h2 id="title" style="position:fixed; width:100%;" class="brdrCol txtCol">$!template.dossiers.list_title</h2>

    <div id="list" class="listDos">
        <table class="defTABLE">
            #foreach($row in $template.dossiers.data.records)
            <tr class="defTR">
                <td class="defTD">$!row.dossiernummer_c</td>
                <td class="defTD">$!row.inzake_c</td>
                <td class="defTD tableLink"><div class="icon-gt txtCol" id="$!row.dossier_id"></div></td>
            </tr>
            #end
        </table>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
<script>
            $(document).ready(onShowHolder());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I tried adding the meta tags for scaling but it didn't help.
 I am using phonegap to build this app.

Comment: I had a panic for a few seconds being convinced that my screen/SO is hacked with someone taking the mouse control over!!! 1+

Comment: Same issue here, but on focus out of `sea` , make `location.reload();` is the only solution I can give for this moment.

Comment: Thanks Jeek, it's not optimal but it's something. There has to be a way to do this properly.. @Neeku haha if I could script that I wouldn't be asking questions here

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap Page scroll up after Keyboard appearance in iOS devices that makes the PhoneGap page corrupted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000660/phonegap-page-scroll-up-after-keyboard-appearance-in-ios-devices-that-makes-the)

Comment: That question is not the same at all, not only have I already tried every solution mentioned there, my html page stays totaly intact except for the white block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in IOS, since I updated my devices to IOS 8 it works way better.
The white block still shows up, but just for half a second and then it disappears again.

Comment: Did you manage to make it without white block at all?  Or the best version you found is to show for half a second? I have the same problem now in iOS 9 that I see a white block where is the keyboard when I close it for half a second. Thanks.

Comment: The problem no longer occurs for me Daniel. 
I'm running ios 9.3.1 and cordova 6.1.1
The delay is also gone for me but I have no idea how I fixed it, sorry

Comment: And what version of cordova-ios engine do you have? I have ~3.9.2 with cordova cli-5.2.0. I want to test with your version to see if this fix my problem. Thanks.

Comment: my IOS version is 4.1.0 I hope this fixes it for you

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with iOS 9 and the solution that I found is to use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView` and the problem is gone.

You can find more details about how to install this here: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView

Comment: Are you sure wkwebview solved it?
I'm still using the UIWebView and experience no issues

Comment: For me I can't fixed the problem with `UIWebView` and when I change to `WKWebView` the problem fixed. I don't know why. Also I read that `WKWebView` has some speed improvements so I think it's not a bad idea to use it after all.